# Don't know the simplest way to display my matrix in a column, keeps displaying in one row

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to display two-dimensional array in columns. I was thinking something either through or `System.out.print("")` but I don't know how to put it and where to put it.

Can you help me, please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(randomArray(9)));

}

private static int[][] randomArray (int n) {
    int[][] randomMatrix = new int[n][n];

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int rows = 0; rows < n; rows++) {
        for (int columns = 0; columns < n; columns++) {
            Integer r = random.nextInt() % 100;
            randomMatrix[rows][columns] = Math.abs(r);
        }
    }
    return randomMatrix;
}
```

How do I display it in the columns, please? keeps displaying like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVFUW.jpg)

Comment: I'am sorry, but this is not "i'am new and struggling", this is pure lazyness in it's purest form.

Comment: If you used `List`s instead of arrays you could join them (join the cells of a line with tabulation for example, and the lines themselves with linefeeds). Here you could convert your arrays to lists, or you need to iterate over the content of the array and print the separators yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] arrs = randomArray(9);
    for (int[] arr : arrs) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Output now:

```
[53, 74, 85, 48, 65, 42, 85, 64, 90]
[45, 29, 41, 0, 49, 19, 3, 93, 58]
[63, 7, 52, 46, 3, 80, 66, 7, 77]
[6, 60, 10, 57, 28, 89, 64, 64, 82]
[10, 55, 80, 10, 41, 97, 21, 79, 15]
[53, 82, 17, 56, 74, 72, 55, 65, 90]
[2, 89, 1, 80, 50, 50, 68, 90, 42]
[6, 50, 60, 11, 56, 3, 56, 48, 45]
[70, 13, 57, 68, 53, 70, 31, 83, 1]
```

Comment: @stafino If you are okay with it, please do remember to mark it as an answer. And if it's good, please remember to upvote it. Thank you ~ BE NICE in StackOverflow ;)

Comment: i wanted to but it is not available next few minutes, will do when possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public void printArray(int[][] inputArray, int n, int m){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0=j<m;j++){
            System.out.println(inputArray[i][j].toString());
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

The above code should give you output in 2d array instead of single line.